# why some time "forward declaration" in the header gave me "Field has incomplete type"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In class A contains a class B object

```
ClassB;
class A
{
    private:
    ClassB b;
}
```

sometimes declare classB is enough, sometimes,I have to use #include "ClassB.h", why? Any difference when using those two?

Answer (score 0):

When forward declaring a class you can only use the forward declared class as a reference or pointer because at this point, the compiler is not aware of the size of this type. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553869/1556026) a good stackoverflow post about what you can and cannot do with forward declarations.